# How to validate the days based on the month input from the user dialogflow

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es

I have created a bot in dialogflow that gets firstname ,lastname, dobyear, dobmonth ,dobday from the user. I want to validate the days in terms of the month I get from the user in webhook nodejs. Example:

bot: enter yourdob -month
user: 02
bot: enter yourdob-date
user:31
bot:enter yourdob-year
user:1994
bot:This is invalid date.

I tried this method below,but did not work.
[image]

Comment: Please post your code as text not as an image. Could you provide some overview? What vale do you expected. Did you follow any guide/docs? Do you restrict values somehow (i.e month cannot have value higher than 12) in your other code part? Did you try to check do it using UI? Did you debug if values are saved correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Well as I see, you can get the number of days that are in the month you provide, then compare with the number that the user put and get set the response depending if the number exceeds or covered